# Roslyn CodeFixProvider add attribute with argument having value

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm creating a CodeFixProvider for the analyzer that is detecting if `MessagePackObject` attribute is missing from the class declaration. Beside, My attribute need to have one argument `keyAsPropertyName` with value `true`

```
[MessagePackObject(keyAsPropertyName:true)]
```

I have done adding attribute without arguments like so(my solution method)

```
private async Task<Solution> AddAttributeAsync(Document document, ClassDeclarationSyntax classDecl, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var root = await document.GetSyntaxRootAsync(cancellationToken);
    var attributes = classDecl.AttributeLists.Add(
        SyntaxFactory.AttributeList(SyntaxFactory.SingletonSeparatedList(
            SyntaxFactory.Attribute(SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("MessagePackObject"))
        //                    .WithArgumentList(SyntaxFactory.AttributeArgumentList(SyntaxFactory.SingletonSeparatedList(SyntaxFactory.AttributeArgument(SyntaxFactory.("keyAsPropertyName")))))))
        //  .WithArgumentList(...)
        )).NormalizeWhitespace());

    return document.WithSyntaxRoot(
        root.ReplaceNode(
            classDecl,
            classDecl.WithAttributeLists(attributes)
        )).Project.Solution;
}
```

But I don't know how add attribute with argument having value. Can somebody help me please?

Comment: Did you try `... .WithArgumentList(SyntaxFactory.AttributeArgumentList(SyntaxFactory.SingletonSeparatedList(SyntaxFactory.AttributeArgument(null, SyntaxFactory.NameColon("keyAsPropertyName"), SyntaxFactory.LiteralExpression(SyntaxKind.TrueLiteralExpression)))))` ?

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria, yes, it works excelent. Answer please, I will mark it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[MessagePackObject(keyAsPropertyName:true)]` is a `AttributeArgumentSyntax` that has NameColons and doesn't have NameEquals, so you just need to create it passing nothing as NameEquals and passing the correct initial expression like this:

```
...
var attributeArgument = SyntaxFactory.AttributeArgument(
    null, SyntaxFactory.NameColon("keyAsPropertyName"), SyntaxFactory.LiteralExpression(SyntaxKind.TrueLiteralExpression));

var attributes = classDecl.AttributeLists.Add(
    SyntaxFactory.AttributeList(SyntaxFactory.SingletonSeparatedList(
        SyntaxFactory.Attribute(SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("MessagePackObject"))
        .WithArgumentList(SyntaxFactory.AttributeArgumentList(SyntaxFactory.SingletonSeparatedList(attributeArgument)))
    )).NormalizeWhitespace());
...
```

Comment: how to call the AddAttributeAsync method and how to find the class

Comment: @KarthicG, advise you to read a tutorial, [for example this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/tutorials/how-to-write-csharp-analyzer-code-fix)